# Web Bluetooth - getting error while connect mobile device to web browser via bluetooth

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I am trying to get Mobile request data to web browser(Laptop) via Bluetooth, so my fist step is connect system bluetooth to web browser, but getting error message by using below code. or is there any other way to connect mobile to web browser via bluetooth to transfer data?

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice().then(
function (d){console.log("found Device !!");}, 
function (e){console.log("Oh no !!",e);});
```

I tried above code in chrome.

Error message :

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestDevice' on 'Bluetooth': 1 argument required, but only 0 present
```

Comment: If you tell us the error message, we can do more than just guessing.

Comment: @Connum - Yes it was heading, i updated.

Comment: You need to provide an `options` object to the argument of `requestDevice` method. Documentation at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth/requestDevice and https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html should get you started in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web which shows you all mandatory options you have to pass:

> For instance, requesting Bluetooth devices advertising the Bluetooth
>   GATT Battery Service is this simple:

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ services: ['battery_service'] }] })
.then(device => { /* ... */ })
.catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```

> If your Bluetooth GATT Service is not on the list of the standardized Bluetooth GATT services though, you may
>   provide either the full Bluetooth UUID or a short 16- or 32-bit form.

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [{
    services: [0x1234, 0x12345678, '99999999-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb']
  }]
})
.then(device => { /* ... */ })
.catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```

> You can also
>   request Bluetooth devices based on the device name being advertised
>   with the `name` filters key, or even a prefix of this name with the
>   `namePrefix` filters key. Note that in this case, you will also need to
>   define the `optionalServices` key to be able to access some services. If
>   you don't, you'll get an error later when trying to access them.

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [{
    name: 'Francois robot'
  }],
  optionalServices: ['battery_service']
})
.then(device => { /* ... */ })
.catch(error => { console.log(error); });
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message tells you, you need to supply an options object to the `requestDevice(options)` method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth/requestDevice